# Laravel consoletvs/charts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, charts

I was trying to implement [Chart](https://erik.cat/projects/Charts/docs/4) with Laravel

For that I was trying to implement the row one with daily date and the column with daily collection ..But I'm not getting proper output means I was getting daily no of transaction not the total amount collected daily.

How do i correct that?

```
   $data = DB::table('carts')
        ->select('carts.created_at', DB::raw('sum(carts.amount) as sum'))
        ->groupBy('carts.created_at')
        ->get(); 

    $chart = Charts::database($data,'area', 'highcharts')
        ->elementLabel("Total")
        ->title('Monthly Collection')
        ->dimensions(1000, 500)
        ->responsive(false)
        ->groupByDay();
```

**UPDATE**

My Cart Table has id,product_name,amount,created_at, updated_at

I wanted to show each day **total(amount)** but it's showing each day **no of carts**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be grouping by `created_at` instead. Basically, you want a total `amount` **per day**, correct?

```
->groupBy('carts.created_at') /* that's the change  */
```

Comment: Yes total amount per day..after i changed with your code I got no of carts created on that day..not the total collection on that day!

Comment: Well, `carts.amount` is the column you use in your post. So, it turns out, the `carts.amount` is the number of carts created. OK. In this case, what is the *collection* column you're talking about? I gather it holds some kind of monetary value. Is it on the same `carts` table?

Comment: yes i wanted to find the total amount transaction per day from from each cart amount

Comment: In this case, you should provide more code for us to take a look at. I don't know what relation is there between the "transaction per day" and the "cart amount". Would you edit your post and explain clearly what you want to achieve and how do those database relations look?

Comment: According to how your `carts` table is structured, the grouping I suggested above should give you what you want - the amount per day. Things you can check: what do you actually store in the `amount` column, and are you sure you are actually *displaying* the correct data on the chart.

Comment: in amount column product value is stored , that's OK!
and data showing correctly means no of carts created that day..But what i want is total of amount created each day that  isn't showing